# What happens to a WatchKit app when iPhone is turned off?

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

Let's say I want to create a WatchKit app that shows the seconds for the current time.

**What happens if iPhone gets turned off** (e.g. battery drained), then user starts the app on the Watch device?

As far as I know, every (!) code runs on the iPhone (extension app), so my method that "fetches" seconds probably won't respond either. It is hard to imagine, but seems that I cannot get / display the current time on the Apple Watch if iPhone is turned off.

Any experiences on this?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can't do watch faces in the current developer kit.

All current WatchKit apps are extensions of iPhone or iPad apps. As you suggest, if the iOS device is not contactable, nothing will happen.

Apple say that native Watch apps will be coming later.

Comment: What will happen to the apps that is currently front running on apple watch? Will it be killed immediately?

Comment: What do you mean? If the iPhone goes away half way through the interaction?

Comment: Yes, I mean when the watch app is running and suddenly the iPhone goes away like rebooted.

Comment: Who knows? I don't think that's documented and almost no one has seen a Watch yet. In any case, anything that would happen would be on the watch itself, and you have no control over that. Means there's nothing you can do, so just try to catch and deal with errors as best you can.

Answer (score 1):

**Your app will be killed immediately.**

As you mentioned before, WatchKit Extension runs on iPhone, and you're absolutely right. There is only storyboard on Apple Watch.

So, the answer is very simple - *"No code - no App"*

Comment: Is this an official quote?

Comment: Paragraph "Apple Watch and Its Paired iPhone":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html